# Failing to connect to Microsoft Bookings API

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, guzzle

I am trying to pull Microsoft Booking calendar data into my WP site.

I have created the required web app and granted my user the required access and delegation to connect to the app, and gave my app access to ‘Microsoft Graph’ and selected ‘Manage bookings information’ and read and write.

I am using PHP, and below is my code: but I am always getting this error although I know for a fact that I am using the right credentials:
Error: HTTP request failed with code 403. Response: {"error":{"code":"ErrorAccessDenied","message":"Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."}}NULL

```
<?php
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use GuzzleHttp\\Client;
    use GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\RequestException;

    function bookings_init($calendar){
        $clientId = "MY_CLIENT_ID";
        $clientSecret = "MY_SECRET_ID";
        $tenantId = "MY_TENANT_ID";
        $username = "MY_USER_EMAIL";
        $password = "MY_PASSWORD";
        $accessToken = getAccessToken($clientId, $clientSecret, $tenantId, $username, $password);

        if ($accessToken) {
            $businessId = "BUSINESS_ID";
            $start = "2023-09-25T08:00:00Z";
            $end = "2023-10-25T17:00:00Z";
        
            $bookingsData = retrieveBookingsData($accessToken, $businessId, $start, $end);
        
            if ($bookingsData) {
                var_dump($bookingsData);
            }
        }
    }

    function getAccessToken($clientId, $clientSecret, $tenantId, $username, $password){
        $client = new GuzzleHttp Client();
        $response = $client->post("https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token", \[
            'form_params' => [
            'grant_type'    => 'password',
            'client_id'     => $clientId,
            'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
            'scope'         => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
            'username'      => $username,
            'password'      => $password
        ],
    ]);

       $body = $response->getBody();
       $data = json_decode($body, true);
       return $data['access_token'];
    }

    function retrieveBookingsData($accessToken, $businessId, $start, $end) {
        $bookingsEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/getSchedule";
        $payload = [
            'Schedules' => [$businessId],
            'StartTime' => [
            'dateTime' => $start,
            'timeZone' => 'UTC'
            ],
                'EndTime' => [
                'dateTime' => $end,
                'timeZone' => 'UTC'
            ]
        ];

       $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
       try {
           $response = $client->request('POST', $bookingsEndpoint, [
               'headers' => [
                   'Authorization' => "Bearer $accessToken",
                   'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
               ],
               'json' => $payload
           ]);
    
           $body = $response->getBody();
           return $body->getContents();
       } catch (RequestException $e) {
           echo "HTTP request failed with code {$e->getCode()}. Response: {$e->getResponse()-  
            getBody()-\>getContents()}";
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it the request in retrieveBookingsData() which gives that 403? Did you succesfully obtain a valid access token prior to that (such that `$accessToken` contains a valid value)? Has your app registration in AAD been given the relevant permissions has detailed at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-getschedule?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions ?

Comment: P.S. Is there a specific reason why you build these requests yourself rather than using the ready-made [PHP SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php) for the Graph API? If you use that, then you can follow the PHP examples in the official documentation much more easily, for one thing, and also it's less likely you'll make some small error in the construction of the HTTP requests, plus you don't have to construct your own data structures for the payload and response data.

Comment: I am getting a valid token, the error is appearing afterwards. I have limited experience in dealing with APIs. I will check the PHP SDK link you provided. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. You should also check the permissions in the app registration in AAD, as I mentioned